# Assigning image from variations of text in array

Tags: arrays, swift

I'm assigning an image based off of the name of a label. For example, if the label says "Car" then the image assigned is the "CarImage" I have it working with this code:

```
  if cell.nameLabel.text == “Car” {
  if let image = UIImage(named: “CarImage”)
  { cell.imageView?.image = image 
  }
  }
```

I want to be able to set many variations of the label for the same image. I am trying this with an array:

```
if cell.nameLabel.text == [“Car”, “Automobile”, “Auto”, "Vehicle",] {
if let image = UIImage(named: “Car”)
{ cell.imageView?.image = image 
  }
  }
```

However I have tried this in several different ways and it is not working. I've read several different answers but none seem to have a clean way of doing this. Thank you for any input!

Answer (score 0):

```
let array = ["Car", "Automobile", "Auto", "Vehicle"]
if array.contains(where: {cell.nameLabel.text != nil && $0 == cell.nameLabel.text!}) {
   cell.imageView.image = UIImage(named: "CarImage")
}
```

The `array.contains(where: {cell.nameLabel.text != nil && $0 == cell.nameLabel.text!})` will check if any of the strings in the `["Car", "Automobile", "Auto", "Vehicle"]` array have the string in `cell.nameLabel.text`. If so, set the image on the cell.

You could get fancy and do something like this:

```
cell.imageView.image = array
      .first(where: {cell.nameLabel.text != nil && $0 == cell.nameLabel.text!})
      .flatMap({_ in UIImage(named: "CarImage")})
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I am getting the error "Variable binding in a condition requires an initializer"